# How to pass array as a parameter to postgress function using hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have postgres function

```
select public.getinventoryhistory('05/01/2017','05/09/2017','{2,3}'::int[]);
```

Now i want to pass this arguments to postgres function using hibernate.

I written java code this way

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select public.getinventoryhistory(:startDate,:endDate,:arrayParameter)");
sqlQuery.setParameter("startDate", startDate);
sqlQuery.setParameter("endDate", endDate);
sqlQuery.setParameter("arrayParameter", new Integer[]{2,3});
```

but above code is not working and getting exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input Position: 648
```

any solution for this ?

Comment: What is the error? Simply pass the array into corresponding parameter.

Comment: @parladneupane getting this exception org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
  Position: 649

Comment: well , i did not see any where clause , post detail function

Comment: @parladneupane i just updated error please look into it.

Comment: try below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not close one of the parenthesis in your code **")"**. Your code should look like

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select public.getinventoryhistory(:startDate,:endDate,:arrayParameter)");
```

check that.

Comment: ok, the adding of  `")`  is require anyway, have you try putting it? , Is there a new error?

Comment: Also you are type casting , `{2,3}'::int[]`,  you should use `IN(2,3)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Calling stored procedure in postgre and mysql is similar in hibernate.

Procedure in mysql that accepts array:

```
DELIMITER ;;
create procedure listPhones(in numbers varchar(255))

BEGIN

set @query = concat('select * from phone where number in (',numbers,');');
prepare sql_query from @query;
execute sql_query;

END
;;

DELIMITER ;
```

To call it from hibernate do :

```
@Test
    public void testProcedure() {
        saveData();

        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        StoredProcedureQuery procedure = session.createStoredProcedureQuery("listPhones");
        procedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(0, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);

        List<Object[]> phones = procedure.setParameter(0, "22222287832,33333287832").getResultList();
        phones.forEach(array -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)));
    }
```

You can find more at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp